# Advice for bit level manipulation

Tags: optimization, cuda, bit-manipulation, gpu

I'm currently working on a project that involves a lot of bit level manipulation of data such as comparison, masking and shifting. Essentially I need to search through chunks of bitstreams between 8kbytes - 32kbytes long for bit patterns between 20 - 40bytes long.

Does anyone know of general resources for optimizing for such operations in CUDA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a least a couple of questions on SO on how to do text searches with CUDA. That is, finding instances of short byte-strings in long byte-strings. That is similar to what you want to do. That is, a byte-string search is much like a bit-string search where the number of bits in the byte-string can only be a multiple of 8, and the algorithm only checks for matches every 8 bits. Search on SO for CUDA string searching or matching, and see if you can find them.

I don't know of any general resources for this, but I would try something like this:

Start by preparing 8 versions of each of the search bit-strings. Each bit-string shifted a different number of bits. Also prepare start and end masks:

```
start
01111111 
00111111 
...
00000001

end
10000000
11000000
...
11111110
```

Then, essentially, perform byte-string searches with the different bit-strings and masks.

If you're using a device with compute capability >= 2.0, store the shifted bit-strings in global memory. The start and end masks can probably just be constants in your program.

Then, for each byte position, launch 8 threads that each checks a different version of the 8 shifted bit-strings against the long bit-string (which you now treat like a byte-string). In each block, launch enough threads to check, for instance, 32 bytes, so that the total number of threads per block becomes 32 * 8 = 256. The L1 cache should be able to hold the shifted bit-strings for each block, so that you get good performance.